# Retrieving column value from target entity if we have primary key in source entity using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where I need to fetch column values from a target entity.

```
EntityComposite - id, pId, qId, pName, qName
EntityP - id, pName
EntityQ - id, qName
```

I have created a entity class for EntityComposite and it has following variables -

```
class EntityComposite {
 private String id;
 private String pId;
 private String qId;
 private String pName;
 private String qName;

}
```

I am able to persist the EntityComposite with properties (id, pId, qId), but while retrieving I want to retrieve all the variables (idd, pId, qId, pName and qName)

Any suggestions?

Also, there is OneToMany mapping between EntityComposite to EntityPa and EntityQ.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this should be the correct mapping:

```
@Entity
class EntityComposite {
 @Id
 private String id;

 @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="pId")
 private EntityP entityP;

 @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="qId")
 private EntityQ entityQ;
}
```

But if it's a one-to-many:

```
@Entity
class EntityComposite {
 @Id
 private String id;

 @OneToMany
 private Set<EntityP> pEntities;

 @OneToMany
 private Set<EntityQ> qEntities;
}
```

Now when you get `EntityComposite` you will also get the associated entities.
For example:

```
List<EntityComposite> result = session
    .createQuery("from EntityComposite")
    .getResultList();
```

I would suggest to look at [the Hibernate ORM guide for mapping associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations).

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the fields of EntityP and EntityQ

```
@Entity
class EntityComposite {
 @Id
 @Column(name="id")
 private String id;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name="eid_p")
 private List<EntityP> pEntities;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name="eid_q")
 private List<EntityQ> qEntities;
}
```

Create EntityComposite repository

```
public interface EntityCompositeRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityComposite,int>{
}
```

Call findAll() in service class

```
@Autowired
private EntityCompositeRepository entityCompositeRepository;

List<EntityComposite> result = entityCompositeRepository.findAll();
```

The result contains the values of fields of both EntityP and EntityQ